# How is the expected value of this estimator found?

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

In problem 4, part C in this online probability book, how is the result pictured below found?  (Near the bottom of the answer)

https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter9/9_1_10_solved_probs.php[image]

Shouldn't it be: $EX^2 - 2E[X*X_M^{\text{^}}] + E[ X_M^{\text{^2}}]$?

Answer (score 0):

They are in fact the same since

$E[X\hat{X}_M]$ $= P(Y=0)E[X\hat{X}_M \mid Y=0] + P(Y=1)E[X\hat{X}_M \mid Y=1]$

$= P(Y=0)E[E[X\mid Y=0] \hat{X}_M \mid Y=0] + P(Y=1)E[E[X\mid Y=1] \hat{X}_M \mid Y=1]$

$= P(Y=0)E[\hat{X}_M^2 \mid Y=0] + P(Y=1)E[\hat{X}_M^2 \mid Y=1]$

$= E[\hat{X}_M^2]$

so $E[X^2] -2E[X\hat{X}_M] + E[\hat{X}_M^2] = E[X^2] -E[\hat{X}_M^2]$

and this is very similarly to the variance calculation $E[(X-E[X])^2] = E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$

Comment: How did you get from $E[X X_M^{\text{^}} | Y = 0]$ to $E[E[X|Y=0]X_M^{\text{^}} | Y = 0]$ ?  Why were you able to distribute out the $X_M^{\text{^}}$?

Comment: @OliverG conditioned on $Y=0$ or indeed any other particular value, $\hat{X}_M^2$ is constant